# Eliminate $t$ in this expression.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation: 
$$C =  \frac{-4 b^2 \left(t^2 w-1\right)^2+8 b \left(t^6 w^2+t^4 \left(w-2 w^2\right)+t^2 (w-2)+1\right)+3 w \left(3 t^4 w-2 t^2 (w+1)+1\right)}{4 \left(t^2 w-1\right)^2}$$
and was wondering whether there is a way of making this expression independent of $t$, that would not require taking $w=0$? So $b$ is a fixed parameter and I am supposed to find all $w$ such that this expression does no longer depend on $t$ anymore. But $w$ is trivial, so I am looking for more ways to do this.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.
EDIT: I also have this equation which may be slightly simpler, as it does not contain a term $t^6$. $$C=\frac{-4 b^2 \left(t^2 w-1\right)^2-12 b \left(t^4 (w-2) w+2 t^2-1\right)+3 w \left(3 t^4 w-2 t^2 (w+1)+1\right)}{4 \left(t^2 w-1\right)^2}$$

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that such a $w$ exists?

Comment: it should exist for at least one of the two equations given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to break it to you, but no such constant $w$ exists for either expression, not even $w = 0$.  I checked twice in *Mathematica*.  The computational approach is to calculate the series expansion of $C(t)$ about $t = 0$, which extracts the constant terms and whose coefficients for higher powers of $t$ must be zero if there exists a choice of $w$ such that $C(t)$ is independent of $t$.  This results in a solution for $w$ in terms of $b$, but when this solution is substituted, the result does not eliminate $t$.  So no such $w$ exists.  Maybe you need to check your work to confirm your question.

Comment: thank you, in that case I really need to recheck my calculations.